# Gas diffusion through a flat plate boundary layer

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinetic-theory

**Set-up**

Suppose we have a flat plate with a flow of gas parallel to the plate. The flow creates a boundary layer on the surface of the plate. Now, the gas is carrying a reactive species, which is adsorbed onto the plate at a certain rate. This causes a lower concentration of the reactive species near the surface of the plate, relative to the main flow. Because of the finite time needed for the reactive species to diffuse through the boundary layer to the plate, a gradient in partial pressure (or, equivalently, in partial number density) will form.

**My question is this:**

How does the partial pressure (or number density) of the reactive species close to the plate depend on the boundary layer thickness? What other parameters are of importance here?

Comment: You actually get two boundary layers: a momentum and species density boundary layer. Their relative size is determined from the [Schmidt number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_number).  The contribution by the flow is captured by the [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number).